# Why does Vulkan forbid uniforms that are not uniform blocks?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

According to [Vulkan Specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/deb236c8daa11e6a4fa41fe4182040ff99fa336f/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt#L62),

> The following features are removed:
>
> - default uniforms (uniform variables not inside a uniform block)

For example, the following is forbidden in GLSL:

```c
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
```

Instead, it seems, programmers are encouraged to create a uniform block:

```c
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform Projection {
    mat4 matrix;
} projection;
```

Using single-valued uniforms is sometimes useful for smaller applications. What was the rationale behind removing the functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in keeping with Vulkan's philosophy of being more explicit, where the application makes the decisions the driver otherwise would. It's not efficient for GPUs to manage single uniforms in isolation; they will be inevitably aggregated into some kind of uniform block under the hood. So Vulkan exposes only uniform blocks and lets you make those decisions yourself. You *can* use a single uniform block per variable if you really want to, but you'll have to explicitly allocate memory for them separately.